# Is using cross-entropy enough to ensure the output is a distribution probability?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, optimization, loss-function, probability

I am following along https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/finetuning_torchvision_models_tutorial.html.

In this code, the last layers of the pretrained networks are linear. The loss used in this classification problem is the cross entropy.

I understand why cross entropy would be a good idea, **given that the output of the layer is a probability distribution**. However, if the last layer is linear, there is no guarantee that the output can be treated as such.

Hence the question : does cross entropy loss naturally lead the output to converge towards a probability distribution during the optimization process, or is there another way to interpret cross entropy when calculated over something that's not a probability distribution ?

Comment: I currently pass the last layer through a softmax (recommended elsewhere), as oppsosed to taking it directly from the linear layer. I can't see much of a difference in a single model, but I adapted the code to perform ensemble learning, and now the predictions can be much more easily combined